# Opencv Window Capture returns blackscreen

Tags: c++, windows, winapi

I've started to experiment/discover opencv but I just can't find what my error is here. I try to get a screenshot of a specific window but I always get a blackscreen as a result. I've tried many different windows to be sure its not a specific problem. ShowWindow works and brings the right Window in the foreground.

```
HWND hwnd = FindWindow(NULL, L"Window Name");

ShowWindow(hwnd, SW_RESTORE);
SetForegroundWindow(hwnd);

RECT rect;
GetClientRect(hwnd, &rect);

long width = rect.right - rect.left;
long height = rect.bottom - rect.top;

HDC hdcScreen = GetDC(hwnd);
HDC hdcMem = CreateCompatibleDC(hdcScreen);
HBITMAP hBitmap = CreateCompatibleBitmap(hdcScreen, width, height);
SelectObject(hdcMem, hBitmap);
BitBlt(hdcMem, 0, 0, width, height, hdcScreen, 0, 0, SRCCOPY);


cv::Mat screenMat(height, width, CV_8UC4);
BITMAPINFOHEADER bi = { sizeof(BITMAPINFOHEADER), width, -height, 1, 32, BI_RGB };
GetDIBits(hdcMem, hBitmap, 0, height, screenMat.data, (BITMAPINFO*)&bi, DIB_RGB_COLORS);

DeleteObject(hBitmap);
DeleteDC(hdcMem);
ReleaseDC(hwnd, hdcScreen);

cv::imshow("Screenshot", screenMat);
cv::waitKey(0);
```

I've tried using different windows, none work. Also tried screenshot of my Desktop which works!:

```
HDC hdcScreen = GetDC(NULL);
HDC hdcMem = CreateCompatibleDC(hdcScreen);
HBITMAP hBitmap = CreateCompatibleBitmap(hdcScreen, 800, 800);
SelectObject(hdcMem, hBitmap);
BitBlt(hdcMem, 0, 0, screenWidth, screenHeight, hdcScreen, 0, 0, SRCCOPY);

Mat screenMat(screenHeight, screenWidth CV_8UC4);
BITMAPINFOHEADER bi = { sizeof(BITMAPINFOHEADER), screenWidth, -screenHeight, 1, 32, BI_RGB };
GetDIBits(hdcMem, hBitmap, 0, screenHeight, screenMat.data, (BITMAPINFO*)&bi, DIB_RGB_COLORS);
```

Also consulted openai to help me but it should work is what I've been told :)

Comment: That's not an OpenCV facility though. that is some random custom WinAPI code that someone once wrote. it's nowhere to be found in OpenCV. google for parts of this winapi code to find other people who've had similar issues: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=GetDIBits+screenMat.data